# Django ORM - update ForeignKey field with model's ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   organizations = models.ManyToManyField(Organization)
   active_organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
```

Now I want to update `active_organization` with one of the `organizations` within the model, so I want to do something like this:

```
User.objects.filter(active_organization=q).update(active_organization=F('organizations__pk')[0])
```

sadly F is not subscriptable, I've also tried,

```
User.objects.filter(active_organization=q)\
                    .update(active_organization=Subquery(
                    Organization.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('organizations').all()[0].pk)))
```

But in this case it tells me the `OuterRef` should be inside a `SubQuery` which it is, so I'm completely at a loss here how this should be approached.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the annotate create a field to then use in the update statement.

```
User.objects.filter(active_organization=q).annotate(
    next_active_org_id=Subquery(
        Organization.objects.filter(
            user_set__id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('id')[:1]
    )
).update(active_organization=F('next_active_org_id'))
```